# How to check if a function is being called every time after executing another function

Tags: javascript

This is how to check if a function is being called before executing another function everytime, my question is how to ensure if secondCall() is being called every time after execution of firstCall() ?

```
var isFirstCalled = false;

function firstCall() {
  isFirstCalled = true;

  ...
}

function secondCall() {
  if (!isFirstCalled) {
   //do something
  }


  isFirstCalled = false;
}
```

Comment: you want to call second after first always automatically or before executing you want to check if first was called earlier .. and what if `first` was called once and `second` is called twice

Comment: Call `secondCall()` from inside `firstCall()`